# Podman bind mount not working with absolute path

Tags: podman

I am trying to bind mount an absolute directory with `-v`.  I see examples showing the full path so why does it not work for me?

```
cd ~/src
podman run -it  \
 -v /Users/user/src/myapp:/app \
  myapp-container /bin/bash

Error: statfs /Users/user/src/myapp: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Try and follow "[Favoring Podman over Docker Desktop](https://medium.com/@butkovic/favoring-podman-over-docker-desktop-33368e031ba0)" from [Peter Butkovic](https://twitter.com/typek_pb) (mentioned in [issue 8016](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/8016)).

You need to create a podman machine

```
podman machine init --cpus=4 --disk-size=60 --memory=6096 -v $HOME:$HOME
podman machine start
mkdir test-dirtouch test-dir/test-file.txtpodman run -v ./test-dir:/opt ubuntu ls /opt
test-file.txt
```

Check also your podman version. [PR 13849](https://github.com/containers/podman/pull/13849) shows "`$HOME:$HOME` by default in `podman machine init`" supported from podman 4.1+ (Apr/May 2022)

[Issue 8302](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/8302) does specify Volumes over remote are not supported.
The podman remote client will try to bind mount the file on the server side.